# TeXShop command line arguments

Tags: texshop

Is there, somewhere, some documentation explaining what arguments TeXShop accepts when started, for example with the shell command "open" on mac os X?

My specific problem is that I would like to be able to open a pdf at a specific page with TeXShop, from a unix shell script. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: If only there were a way to automatically execute TeXShop's typesetter on launch :(

Answer (score 7):

TeXShop does not accept command line options.

The `open` command allows a few (run `open --help`), but they only allow you to do generic things like open the file without bringing TeXShop to the foreground.

**Edit**: The `open` command does accept the `--args` option, which allows you to pass arguments directly to any application. These arguments are passed to the application's `main` function. TeXShop's `main` function does not do anything with its arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask how you know for sure that TexShop does not accept command line arguments? One thing that open lets you do is pass an argument to the app you're opening.

Comment: I had never noticed that, but TeXShop doesn't seem to support arguments anyway. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a way of checking for sure that TeXShop doesn't support arguments? I mean, did you see it written officially somewhere in the documentation, or did you experiment in a conclusive way? I agree that it doesn't look like it supports such arguments, but I'd like to have a more definite answer than an impression.

Comment: I quickly looked inside the source code for the obvious things (mainly argument handling code inside `main.c`). Of course there may be other ways to extract command line arguments. In this case, however, it is highly unlikely.

Comment: Another argument against this type of command line argument is that TeXShop integrates with AppleScript. Even with AppleScript, there is no way to go to a certain page in the PDF, and it seems unlikely that TeXShop would expose something via a command line option and not through AppleScript. Furthermore, TeXShop includes (internally) a shell script to go to a certain source line (used with TeX's `TEXEDIT` variable). The shell script is just wrapped AppleScript. It would be strange if TeXShop accepted command line arguments but didn't use them in its own code.