# How to open TeXShop remotely the command line

Tags: mac, texshop

How would one open TeXShop, say, via command line using `ssh` and X-forwarding?

Comment: Nevertheless, on your local machine, typing `open -a TeXShop` in a shell should open the application, but this would not work through a `ssh` connexion.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: TeXshop is not a X-11 application, it's a native Mac one. As such, it cannot be run remotely over a `ssh` session. It can be opened locally from the Terminal using

```
open -a TeXshop
```

Note also that TeXshop does not read command line parameters: [TeXShop command line arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62943/texshop-command-line-arguments)