# Passing parameters to LaTeX - but in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, parameters

This kind of question [has been asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document), but I didn't see any involving using a GUI to pass parameters (doc class, new conditionals) to a LaTeX document.  I would be interested in some precise instructions for this in TeXShop - presumably one can bind the "Typeset" commands to some `pdflatex params my file.tex` or something, but I have a feeling it would take a lot of error-prone trial and error for me to do that properly.  (I did see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62943/texshop-command-line-arguments) but it seemed not the same.)  Curious if someone has a quick answer, thanks!

Comment: For TeXShop you can just write a new 'engine` based on an existing one. Take a look in the TeXShop folder in your personal Library tree. Might be in something like Application Support or Preferences. You can see how engines are made and copy the `pdflatex` one and then modify it as you wish. Or, if you want it always to do this, you can probably modify the command in the Preferences. Another option is to use something like Arara.

Comment: Right.  Hmm, maybe what I meant was to have a way to easily switch back and forth between a parameter version and a non-parameter version... I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Well, you can easily switch from one engine to another. Or you can easily alter the Arara line and then just use a single Arara engine.

Comment: By "easily" you don't mean "one keyboard shortcut per engine", though, right?  This is ideally what I'm interested in (rather than having to go into the menus every time).

Comment: Why not? It is a long time since I used it, but I assume TeXShop allows you to configure keyboard shortcuts for engines. I'm almost sure it allowed you to do this even in the much older versions I used.

Comment: I couldn't find this (sorry for the long comment thread) - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82382/does-texshop-for-mac-have-key-bindings is not what I'm looking for.  I just can't find a place to have *two* custom engines accessible with a shortcut - lots of places to change the default, but not even a plist file that was appropriate... I can change what each engine does but of course on a one-time basis.

Comment: I'm sure you can do this. If not, you can just use the standard `TS` lines at the top to switch between engines. But the only available documentation for TS is from 2006 unless you have access to TS and can read the help. Since I don't, I can only see the 2006 documentation which is unlikely to be helpful. So I can only suggest you read the help.